# How to model spawning after kill/miss in Predator-Prey model in Netlogo?

Tags: netlogo

I'm working on a [Predator-Prey model](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/models/WolfSheepPredation) but I have a unique spawning mechanic that I'm trying to work in.

The idea is that when a wolf encounters sheep, there is a probability of the sheep escaping (I already have this part coded in). If the sheep is killed, *n* number of lambs are created. If the sheep escapes, *k* number of lambs are created. After *t* periods, the lambs become prey. *n, k*, and *t* will all be sliders on the interface side.

I'm pretty new to agent-based modeling and Netlogo coding, so any advice would be really appreciated.

This is the current code for the hunting:

```
to catch-sheep  ;; wolf procedure
    let prey one-of sheep-here   
    if prey != nobody and random 100 < kill-probability 
        [ ask prey [ die ]
```

Comment: And what is your current problem with the code you provided?

Comment: Oh no, the code I have for the kill-prob works just fine. My problem is that I'm trying to add on to it. I want to have it such that every time a wolf and a sheep encounter each other, depending on how the interaction goes (kill or miss) some number of lambs are being created.

Answer (score 0):

Presumably k>n, so you can have all adult sheep `hatch` n lambs, and then `catch-sheep`, and then have all remaining adult sheep hatch k-n lambs.  This requires distinguishing between lambs and adults, so you may want to add an `age` attribute.

However, I suspect you will want to switch to probabilities of hatching a lamb each tick, rather than a number of lambs hatched each tick.

Answer (score 0):

Using your code to add some code and see if that works for you.

When a sheeps is killed create a random number of new sheeps, in the code below use your slide variable instead of 10.

I use the [primitive function hatch](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dict/hatch.html) to do all the work.

```
to catch-sheep  ;; wolf procedure
    let prey one-of sheep-here   
    if prey != nobody and random 100 < kill-probability 
        [ ask prey [ die ] 
          ;;Here we create new sheeps upon prey death
          let rd-num random 10 ;; 1 to 10 sheeps will appear
          hatch-sheep rd-num [ set color blue
                              set xcor 9 ;; Initialize your new sheeps ]
        ]
```

Let us know of any questions you might have! Happy coding.

Comment: This is really helpful, thank you! 

I do have another question. Is there a command that I can add that'll let me control how many ticks it'll take for the new Sheep to enter the system? If this is possible, can I also make their entering contingent upon the Sheep population being positive?

Comment: To control increase of sheeps in time you could use simple math, for example if you want a sheep to appear every `k` ticks you can ask somewhere in your code if `tick mod k = 0`, if this is true then you create a new sheep. Check the [modulo](https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#mod) documentation about this.